# What to call a river harbor?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would you call a place where several boats are kept on a river? "Harbor" sounds wrong to me, as I associate it with the sea.

Here is an example of such a place in Brazil, from [this Google Street View photo sphere](https://www.google.no/maps/@-8.8377176,-69.2562674,3a,89.7y,97.5h,56.6t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s7kPH_-cUMn9psmk1b4rjJQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656):

[image]

Comment: I would call it a "landing area"--from the photo both "harbor" and "port" imply facilities or construction that doesn't appear to be there.  @Tor, could you fix the spelling in the title, please?  And capitalize Google (Google Earth?) More informally "take-out" may be a description of the area.

Comment: Is it a marina or a dock?

Comment: looks like a mooring or moorage (or landing area or port). contra @Xanne, I don't think "port" implies deluxe facilities. "harbor" is wrong since a harbor implies a bay or sheltered area for water craft

Comment: It's a bend in the river with a sandy area--what in river rafting or canoeing is called a take-out area.

Answer (score 3):

I'd describe this as a **moorage**.

> [A place where a ship or aircraft may be moored](http://www.yourdictionary.com/moorage)

Other options would be **mooring**

> [a place for mooring a vessel](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mooring)

(boat) **landing** (area) (as suggested by @Xanne)

and

**port**, which can refer to the part of town where boats are moored.

Answer (score 0):

Riverport or An inland port is a port on an inland waterway, such as a river, lake, or canal, which may or may not be connected to the sea.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).